# Is it a bad practice: embed QML in a QT dockable widgets application?

Tags: qt, qml

the QT widget is very time consuming in terms of UI development, my CSS sheets has 3000 lines of code already and it is very time consuming to do UI changes. My application is very demanding in terms of performance, I was thinking of embedding the widgets into QML to have easier and faster control of the UI but I'm really worried about performance, will worth the try or it is just bad practice?

Answer (score 2):

> My application is very demanding in terms of performance, I was
>   thinking of embedding the widgets into QML to have easier and faster
>   control of the UI but I'm really worried about performance, will worth
>   the try or it is just bad practice?

Since Qt 5.1 we can easily embed QML view to Qt Widget container. There is a blog I stumbled upon some time ago: [Combining Qt Widgets and QML with QWidget::createWindowContainer()](http://www.ics.com/blog/combining-qt-widgets-and-qml-qwidgetcreatewindowcontainer).

As for performance, unsure what kind of performance is in demand for your application? Overall QML renders to screen via OpenGL or very fast. On the other hand with QML you often need to deal with JavaScript which of course is not comparable to C++. There is [Qt Quick Compiler](http://doc.qt.io/QtQuickCompiler/) introduced to commercial Qt, though.

As for QWidget-based UI vs. QML: the discussion can be considered an expression of opinion etc. Some consideration points then:

- Developing and maintaining one kind of UI, either widget or QML based is easier.
- Hybrid UI is possible but it makes sense to understand what you can gain from it.
- Most desktop apps are fully satisfied with widgets only.
- When the app supposed to be ported to mobile platforms as well then QML makes more sense.
- When the app supposed to rely on 'touch' then QML is also more beneficial than widgets.

> the QT widget is very time consuming in terms of UI development, my
>   CSS sheets has 3000 lines of code already and it is very time
>   consuming to do UI changes.

Hmm... very heavily styled widget-based app? I can only be sure that these two concepts: widgets and QML are very different but both widget stylesheets and QML are declarative language though different. I am also sure that any serious app needs more of C++ and with QML we need to spend time bridging C++ code with QML.

And the distribution of QML apps can also be a bit more complex than purely widget-based: for instance you need to customized Qt build to support OpenGL emulated for certain VMs and platforms: *that is one interesting topic*. Also with Qt Quick widgets you use should put them either to resource distributed with the app or you need Qt Quick Compiler. And if you use it, be sure that all QML code was compiled by it and no part of the app still uses 'scripted' QML which is missing from resources. I made use of Qt 5.5 Quick Compiler in our app and found not only quite a few bugs with it but also still needs to drag certain Qt Quick files from framework together with the app install package. That is not as bad with standard dynamic link and `windeployqt` tool. But a serious app often needs to be statically linked with all its dependencies and then we cannot use `windeployqt` tool.

Overall Qt is departing from widgets to QML but what can we gain and how much we need QML in our real applications is a long discussion.